# Send Azure Metrics chart by email - by any means

Tags: azure, powershell, email, charts, metrics

I manually email out a screenshot of a line chart from the Azure portal (expressroute circuit / metrics / avg bitsinpersecond). Is there any way I can get this to email out automatically on a schedule, or if not, then use Powershell AzureRM or Az CLI to pull the data and produce a chart? From googling I see people recommend NPM but I think that's a bit heavy for my needs here.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not using PowerShell or CLI, with Logic Apps you can get a chart from Azure Monitor using the [Azure Monitor Logs Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azuremonitorlogs/). For this I believe, you would have to first setup [the Express Route related Solution to Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/network-performance-monitor-expressroute).

Here is an [awesome blog](https://blog.cloudtrooper.net/2019/06/30/sending-log-analytics-tables-and-charts-per-email-with-a-logic-app/) that covers creating a Logic App using these connectors. You would have to change the queries to fetch metrics for your express route resource.